# Resize partition from virtual machine without reboot

Tags: partitioning, virtualization

I run several virtual ubuntu machines on a proxmox server. They all have a single disk without LVM. When disk space runs out I poweroff the virtual machine, then enlarge the partition, mount gparted ISO, boot from this ISO, resize the partition, and boot the vm again.

Now I wonder if there is a simpler way without rebooting the virtual machine.

Comment: Just `sudo reboot`.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle some informations about the root filesystem:

```
df /
# Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
# /dev/sda2       31365948 5249140  24500424  18% /
```

`/dev/sda2` is the second partition of block device `/dev/sda`.
To size up this partition, you can use the tool `parted`.

```
parted /dev/sda
# (parted) resizepart 2
# Warning: Partition /dev/sda2 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?
# Yes/No? yes
# End?  [41.0GB]? 82GB
# (parted) q
# Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

After changing size of partition, you have to size up the filsystem too:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda2
# resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
# Filesystem at /dev/sda2 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
# old_desc_blocks = 4, new_desc_blocks = 9
# The filesystem on /dev/sda2 is now 18019403 (4k) blocks long.
```

This is for checking modifications:

```
df /
# Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
# /dev/sda2       70817420 5253016  62349464   8% /
```

Comment: Is there a way to resize to max? I'm not exactly sure what to put for GB

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to resize to max

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan

partprobe

use gdisk or parted

gdisk fix warning and extend disk manually

parted change partion size

## parted can executed as command line. but this is very dangerous
parted -s /dev/sdb "resizepart 2 -1" quit
parted -s /dev/sdb "resizepart 3 100%" quit
resizepart 3 100%

pvresize /dev/sda3

lvextend -l +100%FREE cs/root

xfs_growfs /dev/cs/root
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).